# Validation Rule Query

Tags: formula, validation

create a validation rule on Org_c object that fires when:
if Account.Name = 'Joo' and org_credential_r.name is changing to 'AAT-AAT' and
Approval = true and 'Priority' NOT Equal to 'High'.

Pls exclude user  sharan G

```
Account.Name = "Joo" &&
ISCHANGED( Org_Credential__c) &&
Org_Credential__r.Name = "AAT-AAT" &&
Approval_c= TRUE &&
TEXT( Priority) <> "High" &&
$User.Username <> "sharan.g@explore.com"
```

I tried the above formula, its not triggering the validation rule
please help

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). What happens if you only try one of those at a time? Which one (if any) fails to work as expected?

Comment: ISChanged is bit confusing - whenever user checks Approval_c, and saves the record and then he again changes the org_credentail to AAT-AAT, its not throwing the error message, though he meets all the other conditions

Comment: You have connected 6 criteria with `AND` - that means that ALL of those criteria must be met EACH TIME the record is saved in order for it to fire. If a user makes some changes and saves, then makes other changes and saves again, this one rule will not fire.

Comment: Can you please suggest or provide the rule which meets all criterea

Comment: AND(
Account.Name = 'Joo',
ISCHANGED( Org_Credential__c),
Org_Credential__r.Name = "AAT-AAT",
Approval_c= TRUE,
TEXT( Priority) <> "High",
$User.Username <> "sharan.g@explore.com"
)


Can i try this? i wanted to know the main difference of tis and the initial formula( question Posted)

Comment: I was not clear with my last comment.... Obviously if the 2nd save a user does makes all of those criteria end up being true, even if they only changed some of them but the rest of them already met the other criteria - then this rule would fire.

Comment: Ohh Okay,Thankyou very much 
I'll Check with my team to double check in sandboxes

Comment: Usually people use `AND(...,...)` in formula fields and validation rules rather than `&&`, but your new formula is no different from your original.

Comment: When your requirement says "exclude user Sharan G", does that mean that this rule should *ONLY* fire for Sharan G, or *NEVER* fire for Sharan G?

Comment: Never trigger to sharan, excluding sharan from validation rule

Comment: Is your `Approval__c` field a Checkbox (i.e., Boolean)?

Comment: Yes, Correct  its checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Your validation rule fails because ISCHANGED() cannot reference fields on other objects,
You can complete this task by creating a checkbox field on **org_credential** object and a workflow rule to update checkbox field when name changes.

Follow these steps:

- -Create a checkbox field on **org_credential** object.
  -Create a workflow rule set the Evaluation criteria to created, and every time it's edited.
  -In Rule Criteria select formula evaluates to true.
  -In Rule Criteria body enter `ISCHANGED(Name)`.
  -Click Save&Next.
  -Click Add Workflow Action.
  -Select New field Update.
  -Enter name and Unique name.
  -Select the checkbox field in Field to Update.
  -Select true in Specify New Field Value section.
  -Click save and then Activate.

And then Update your formula field by this formula:

```
(Account__r.Name = "joo") &&    
(org_credential__r.OrgCredNameChanged__c = true) &&
(org_credential__r.Name  = "AAT-AAT")  &&  
(Approval__c = true)  &&  
TEXT( Priority__c) <> "High"
```